# Add tr row depends upon the value of input text value

Tags: jquery, html

By default the table have 2 rows. In the top of fiddle, the textfield have some value. If i change the valuein the text field, the number of rows will be added. I found the following scripts:

```
http://devzone.co.in/add-remove-rows-in-table-dynamically-using-jquery/

http://jsfiddle.net/toddhd/Qt7fH/
```

Here is my fiddle: `<http://jsfiddle.net/ZgKMU/>`

But I cann't to connect these two scripts. Any one help can be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$("#myInputFieldId").on('change',function(){
    var items = $(this).val();
    for(var i=0; i<items; i++){
        $('#preq').find('tr').eq('1').clone().appendTo('#preq');
    };
 });
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgKMU/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myInputFieldId").on("change",function(){ 
var norow= parseInt($("#myInputFieldId").val());
var trlenght=$("#preq tr").length-1;

if(norow>trlenght)
{
    for(var i=0;i<norow-trlenght;i++){
        var tr=$("#preq tr:eq(1)").clone();
        $("#preq tr:last").after(tr);}
}
else if(trlenght>norow)
{

    for(var i=0;i<trlenght-norow;i++){

        $("#preq tr:last").remove();}
}
})
```

Demo link http://jsfiddle.net/anandnat/ZgKMU/2/

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
$("#myInputFieldId").change(function(){ 
       var cnt=$(this).val();
       var totalTr=($("#preq tr").length)-1;
       if(cnt>totalTr){
           for(var i=0;i<cnt-totalTr;i++){
               var lastTR=$("#preq tr:last").html();
               $("#preq").append("<tr>");
               $("#preq tr:last").html(lastTR);
           }
       }
       else{
            for(var i=0;i<totalTr-cnt;i++){
                $("#preq tr:last").remove();
            }
       }
    });
```